# After clicking hardware Menu button, onBackPressed is not called when hardware Back button is clicked

Tags: android

I have a very strange problem with my LG G Pro
It has a hardware Back, Home and Menu buttons.
In an activity in the application, if I click the hardware Menu button,
"onBackPressed" doesn't get called anymore if I tap the hardware Back button.

I tried overcoming this using this piece of code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            if (menu != null) {
                Log.e("Activity", "onKeyUp KEYCODE_MENU");
                return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keycode, e);
}
```

But this doesnt help.

Here is some more code from the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    String buttonText = getString(R.string.action_bar_done);
    MenuItem item = menu.add(MENU_GROUP, MENU_ITEM_DONE_NUMBER, 0, buttonText);
    item.setTitle(buttonText);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this

```
@Override   
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {              
        onBackPressed();
        return true;    
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem. I also edited out some irrelevant `WebView`-related code. Will accept your answer in 5 minutes

Comment: I just copy this code form my android browser app in a hurry

Comment: Sorry for that mistake